# Single query to check results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table(demo):

```
questions
----------
question_id | question       | choice1 | choice2 | choice3 | choice3 | choice4 | answer
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | what is..      | apple   | orange  | grapes  | pinea   | blah    | 2
2           | what is..      | apple   | orange  | grapes  | pinea   | blah    | 4
3           | what is..      | apple   | orange  | grapes  | pinea   | blah    | 1
4           | what is..      | apple   | orange  | grapes  | pinea   | blah    | 2
5           | what is..      | apple   | orange  | grapes  | pinea   | blah    | 3
6           | what is..      | apple   | orange  | grapes  | pinea   | blah    | 4
```

A set of 5 random questions will be displayed to user and then user selects the answer. So, when user submits the form(answersheet), how to check if the `question_id` & `answer` that user had submitted is correct ?

What I do now is, loop through each `question_id` in the submitted answersheet, then do a query to check if the answer is correct like this(**psuedocode**):

```
$wrong_questions = $total_questions_in_answersheet;
foreach($question in $answersheet)
{
   $c = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions` WHERE `question_id` = $question_id AND `answer` = $answer;

   if($c > 0)
     $wrong_questions--;
}

if($wrong_questions > 0)
  echo 'FAILED';
else
  echo 'WELL DONE';
```

Is it possible to do checking of answers in a single query? If so, would it better to do it in that way?

Answer (score 1):

```
$where = implode(' OR ', array_map(function($question) {
    return "(question_id = $question[question_id] AND answer != $question[answer])";
}, $answersheet));

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS wrong_questions FROM questions WHERE $where";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['wrong_questions'] > 0) {
    echo 'FAILED';
} else {
    echo 'WELL DONE';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running query in the loop is generally considered to be a bad practice; so, in fact, I would make only two things:
First, `SELECT` all the correct answer linked to `id`, in associative array, like `$answers['id']['answer']`;
Second, compare submitted answers with `$answers` array by `id`.